# How to get slope of each column for DataFrame with datetime index in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
#from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[100,150,200,250],"B":[100,200,300,400]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2000-12-31', '2001-12-31', '2002-12-31', '2003-12-31']))
```

> ```
>               A   B
> 2000-12-31    100 100
> 2001-12-31    150 200
> 2002-12-31    200 300
> 2003-12-31    250 400
> ```

I want to get a series which contains slopes for each columns.

Comment: How do you define slope in your example? What does the output look like?

Comment: @notiv The slope of date based linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[100,150,200,250],"B":[100,200,300,400]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2000-12-31', '2001-12-31', '2002-12-31', '2003-12-31']))
df.apply(
    lambda x: stats.linregress(df.index.map(datetime.date.toordinal), x)[0]
)
```

It seems that `stats.linregress` could do this job as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707201/1633272) described.

I'm still looking for a clearer way.